# Is it possible to convert a Table-Valued functions in a stored procedure to Spark SQL to run in Azure Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am not able to convert a below Stored Procedure code with Table-Valued functions in OUTER APPLY into Spark SQL code.

```
SELECT T1.col1, T2.col2, fn.col1
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2 ON col1= T2.col1
OUTER APPLY FN_Formula(T1.col,T2.col1) fn
```

Answer (score 0):

SparkSQL does not have table-valued user defined functions in the same way as SQL Server does, but it does support system [table-valued functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-tvf.html) (like range, explode, stack etc), user-defined functions which could be exploded, or just plain rewrites of the same set-logic, eg with a Common Table Expression (CTE) or subquery.  [Higher order functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/16/introducing-new-built-in-functions-and-higher-order-functions-for-complex-data-types-in-apache-spark.html) are also a powerful way to deal with arrays and complex data types.  The best approach kind of depends what you are doing.  Perhaps you can share some about what the function is doing?

Comment: Thanks @wBob. Inside this function we are having multiple temp tables, CTE's, nested if-else logic to update the temp tables based some business rules and finally all the temp tables are merged to return a single table output with multiple records.

Comment: I would suggest refactoring this into normal procedural code.  You can have temporary tables but they write to storage so see if you can do without them.